# Reduced Internet Speed via pfsense-vm

Tags: pfsense, internet-speed

I recently setup pfSense kvm and have a 4 port NIC attached. The WAN port is connected to my ISP router and hooked my PC to LAN for testing. Now, the problem is --

1. While I do iperf to public servers from the pfsense box, it shows my actual internet speed which is around 60Mbps.
2. I do iperf from LAN PC to pfsense box, gives me ~98Mbps (since my PC lan connection is of 100Mbps).
3. Now I do iperf to that public server from my PC, gives speed around **1Mbps** or sometimes less than that.

I'm out of clue, what is going wrong. somebody please enlighten me. Let me know if you want any stats. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found my solution. Enabled the check box for **Hardware Checksum Offloading**. That helped to get proper internet speed at LAN side too.

Whoever may come here later searching for similar pfsense speed related issues, will suggest to play with these 3 options under **System**>**Advanced**>**Networking**/Network Interfaces :: *Hardware Checksum Offloading*, *Hardware TCP Segmentation Offloading*, *Hardware Large Receive Offloading*. Since these things are hardware dependent, options may vary from system to system.